# My website is really slow, how to make it faster

Tags: performance, web

So, my website is done, my website is: http://rocase.win/ But now you go to it, you will see that it is going really slow.

Loading time takes 10-20 seconds. I do an test on pingdom, and they say my loading time is 60 seconds, but almost all the performance is 100%.

Here is the result: https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/bObPdM/http://rocase.win I have tried like deleting all the comments I have, all the blank lines deleting.

But still is the loading time really really long. How can I make this shorter?

Thanks!

Comment: This will also tell you ways to solve the issues.
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

Comment: There are some links from kaspersky that are timed out and make your page slow.  Check they are right.

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow need to contain enough information that the Q&A won't go stale as soon as the links change. Please post the actual code that you think is slow. Also, this site isn't equipped to do code reviews. You would be better off asking on [codereview.se].

Comment: Loads instantly for me

Comment: you tagging this as php and asking us to visit your website, won't do any good. On top of having us fetch its content. Use the developer's network console and debug this yourself.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37061228/faster-website-by-combining-css-files-in-one-file-laravel/37061300#37061300

Comment: I deleted the php tag in an edit, along  with all others since there was no code posted in the question and replaced them with relevant tags. Please dont spam tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the external load of JS and CSS( kaspersky ). Comment or remove this lines of your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/859509E7-F570-4047-AEC0-CEF2BFA49B1B/main.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/B1B94AFB2FEC-0CEA-7404-075F-7E905958/abn/main.css"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have some missing files which result(s) in long timeout,
You are missing some fonts and more....

---

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your main.js and main.css in kaspersky-labs are making your website slow.

Delete your main.js and main.css lines or move files to your host .

Next time you can use Developer Console in Chrome or some browsers.
In Chrome click the Network tab and refresh page. You can see which file is trouble.